# Creating graduated point circles in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, color-ramp

I have not been giving any data, but I have been told that I could be expected to recreate maps In ArcGIS 10. Below is an sample portion of what I may have to recreate. I have no idea  how to get symbology like this for point data. Graduated symbology would only work across the array of points. How do I get one point to have the color variations like seen below? The points are representing observation density. I know how to obtain and symbolize basic data. I don't need information on how to get the hydrology layers or symbolize the eagle point. I need to know how to do the red circles.

Heat maps are not what I need since the "blanket" the entire area.

[image]

Comment: its not direct point symbology. Look at heatmaps.And please specify the software that you are using .

Answer (score 5):

Since the software was not specified. I can recommend how to accomplish the task in QGIS.

I can suggest applying plugin ["Multi Ring Buffer"](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Multi_Ring_Buffer/) if you need **a vector output**. Here you can find a short tutorial [QGIS – Create Multi-Ring Buffers](https://www.cadlinecommunity.co.uk/hc/en-us/articles/115003412285-QGIS-Create-Multi-Ring-Buffers).

Additionally, as was specified by [@radouxju](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25070/radouxju), you can use ["Heatmap"](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_heatmap.html), in case if you require **a raster output**.

Regarding the "...that I could be expected to recreate maps." Yes, you do! For that, you first of all need to find the data which you want to visualize.

So far, I can assume that you need

- some hydrography (e.g. rivers, lakes)
- observation locations
- and data about those figures (i.e. polygons with coloured edges)

About "I have no idea how to get symbology like this for point data." I can suggest creating an SVG graphical element. It looks like an eagle which is inside of the circle. Just find [a free eagle](https://www.flaticon.com/search?word=eagle) and put it inside the circle. And then visualize in QGIS. Do not forget to save it with SVG extension.

Answer (score 4):

In ArcGIS the answer is [Multiple Ring Buffer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/multiple-ring-buffer.htm#L_)

Add your distances and keep the dissolve default setting. Once the new layer is created, pick a ramp of red hue, and style the symbology to fit your graphical needs (suggest removing the "outline color" for all symbol categories and setting transparency to something less than 50%).